# Awk Integer Overflow

Tags: awk, gawk

I think I've encountered some type of overflow in awk, and am not sure how to get around it, see below:

```
BEGIN {
    print 23 * 22 * 21 * 20 * 19 * 18 * 17 * 16 * 15 * 14 * 13 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
    print      22 * 21 * 20 * 19 * 18 * 17 * 16 * 15 * 14 * 13 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
}
```

This is the output:

```
25852016738884978212864
1124000727777607680000
```

While the second is correct, the first is not, 23! is equal to 25852016738884976640000.

Is there anyway to get by this, perhaps some variant?

To be *precise* I am using gawk:

```
GNU Awk 4.0.1
```

Comment: `awk` does not pretend to provide arbitrary precision arithmetic. You might be able to get around it by replacing some of the numbers with a floating point version, but setting `22` to `22.0` did not actually achieve the desired effect.  Use a tool with 'infinite precision' arithmetic; `bc` is one such tool, Python is another.

Comment: If your version of `awk` supports [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic), i.e. makes use of `gmp`, you could supply the `-M` option to get the desired results.

Comment: I had to re-compile gawk with the flags for mpfr which allowed me to use the -M option. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, you can first install `libmpc-dev` then recompile the latest version of `gawk` (4.1) to get it up and working..

Answer (score 2):

using bc

```
$ echo '23 * 22 * 21 * 20 * 19 * 18 * 17 * 16 * 15 * 14 * 13 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1' |bc

25852016738884976640000
```

You can export the awk result to bc command:

```
cat a.awk

BEGIN {
  for (i=23;i>1;i--) printf "%d * ",i ; printf 1 RS
  for (i=22;i>1;i--) printf "%d * ",i ; printf 1 RS
}

awk -f a.awk|bc

25852016738884976640000
1124000727777607680000
```